# Convert time from utc to local time in android in long value

Tags: android, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I receive time from server in seconds in UTC+0000 format.I have converted that time to milliseconds.How do I convert this long milliseconds time into my default timezone time format(in long itself) .I have seen posts that strictly say use Joda-Time Library.I there any way of doing this in native java way.I did try

```
    public static String toDuration(long duration) {
            long time_duration, temp_duration;
            Date now = new Date();
            temp_duration = duration * 1000L;
            int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
            Date date = new Date(temp_duration + offset);

            time_duration = now.getTime() - date.getTime();

            Log.d("Tag", "Now Time" + now.getTime());
            Log.d("Tag", "Date Time" + date.getTime());
            Log.d("Tag", "Long value is : " + time_duration); 
}
```

but this too gives me a negative difference between the two times.Guys please help.I have been stuck on this for a long time.Thanks.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: @Apurva your answer displays time in string format directly..I wanted in the form of long value.

Comment: Not a string, it converts milliseconds into `date` format. Why do you want a `long` time if you can get it in `date` format?

Comment: @Apurva because I have to subtract that long value with another date's long value..

Answer (score 0):

You've complicated yourself up. The server is giving you time in milliseconds and Java's Date takes in time in milliseconds (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long))

So

```
Date time = new Date(duration)
```

will contain the correct server returned time. Time in seconds since Jan 1, 1970 ignores timezones, that's why we love it.

If you then want to output for a specific timezone use Android's DateFormat (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) and set the timezone accordingly.

To find the timezone try TimeZone.getDefault() (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault())

Comment: The input parameter for `Date` is in milliseconds - not seconds.

Comment: @waqaslam I know the server generally returns time in milliseconds but in my case I did clarify it with my web service developer and he says its in seconds..so the need of * 1000L

Comment: @waqaslam also..if i directly use the date without converting ito the timezone local value..i encounter negative values while subtracting two time values..

Comment: @AndroidMech you need to stop thinking about timezones. They are unimportant for things returned in seconds. You need to validate with your webservice developer what they are returning. If they are returning a value in seconds you need to know what that means. If it means seconds since Jan 1 1970 then great, multiply by 1000 and set it in your date. If they mean seconds since midnight in UTC+0000 then you've got a bit of trouble. Because you have to figure out what date it is in Greenwich and work forwards. But once you do you'll end up with a value in millis since 1970.